# Parse Error Installing custom built .apk

Tags: android, parsing, android-install-apk

I have built a simple custom app that we would like to push out to our sales reps phones.  I developed it using Eclipse with the Android SDK and it is written for Android version to 1.5 and the min SDK is set to 3.  I have compiled the app with a private key (not the debug key) and everything compiles without errors.  When I send the .apk file to a few users via email to test, they receive a parse error when clicking on the .apk file.  The following is the content from the log:

WARN/PackageInstaller(2873): Parse error when parsing manifest. Discontinuing installation

However, when one user opened the message in Gmail, they were given the option to Install the .apk and it installs and runs without any problems.

Can anyone tell me if it is possible to email the .apk file to the desired people and have it install directly from an email?  We also saved the .apk file to the SD card and tried to install it from there with the same result.  I found several suggestions about installing a file manager to the phone and using that to install from the SD card.  However, the fewer steps the better when pushing this out to our reps.

Any help would really be appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

> Can anyone tell me if it is possible to email the .apk file to the desired people and have it install directly from an email?

Only if the sending email client puts the right MIME type in the email message.

You are typically better served using something Web-based, either manually set up (use `application/vnd.android.package-archive` as the MIME type), or via something like Dropbox -- put an APK in a shared box, and people with the Android Dropbox client can simply install it from there.

Comment: I know I've had problems emailing apks to people if they download it with the gmail app.

Comment: Hi Everyone - thanks for the great replies.  I will try your suggestion CommonsWare.  I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 4):

don't worry. Its a little problem. I also spend one week behind this and finally I got the solution. Just go to you manifest.xml file and perform fallowing changes.

```
//uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="14"
```

Just change it to

```
//uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="3"
```

Or any lower level sdk version that our device support. Try it. And reply, whether You satisfied or not.

Answer (score 2):

I think, there is problem with your gmail account. Because I always sent .apk file to my client through gmail account. And until I did not get any problem while attaching and sending .apk file. Try with other gmail account for your confirmation.

Answer (score 1):

Package error comes when your sdk version of software does not matches the device sdk version
check appropriate device sdk version and change your software sdk version
you can change by following steps
if you don't have sdk version in eclipse just download it from

Preferences->Android sdk and Avd manager->Available package

after that in project explorer select
Project root->properties->Android
and change version accordingly